# NodeJS + socket.io do I need express?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Simple question. I am building an online browser game using phaser and socket.io. Now I can tell I'll definetly be using socket.io alot but what about express? Once I initiate the server what else would I ever need to do? I feel like  all I need is like 3 lines of code for the http server. Any opinions on what else I would use express for?

Comment: The question is really for you since we don't know what you're doing in your app.  What would you use Express for?  If all you need is a basic http server that socket.io can hook to, then you can even just let the socket.io library create one for you if you just do [`io.listen(port)`](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server(port:number,-opts:object)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just going to use websockets and and no routing besides loading the actual application, then I'd say just use the native http client in node.js and make everything go through socket.io. Express is not needed in my opinion.